# Update with double joins

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I have an access query that I need to have converted to Oracle.  And in access, it uses an inner join that is within an inner join.  I am not an expert at any of this, but I only learned Oracle to an extent and practically nothing in access. (and is not my access string either (creator of it died a year back)).  And I have no choice in its conversion to oracle... it just needs to get done.  :/

anyhow...  here is the string:

```
UPDATE AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY
  INNER JOIN (HISTORY_BOL
    INNER JOIN PERIOD_TO_PROCESS
    ON
      (HISTORY_BOL.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM)
    AND
      (HISTORY_BOL.FSCL_YR_NUM = PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_YR_NUM)
      )
  ON
    (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.LOC_ID = HISTORY_BOL.TO_LOC_ID)
  AND
    (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = HISTORY_BOL.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM)
  AND
    (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.FSCL_YR_NUM = HISTORY_BOL.FSCL_YR_NUM)
SET AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.CASES_RCVD = TOTAL_BOL_SHIP_CASE_QTY;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle likes it differently:

```
MERGE
INTO    AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY
USING   (
  SELECT TOTAL_BOL_SHIP_CASE_QTY, ROWID AS r 
  FROM AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY
  INNER JOIN HISTORY_BOL
  ON
    (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.LOC_ID = HISTORY_BOL.TO_LOC_ID)
  AND
    (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = HISTORY_BOL.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM)
  AND
    (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.FSCL_YR_NUM = HISTORY_BOL.FSCL_YR_NUM)
  INNER JOIN PERIOD_TO_PROCESS
    ON
      (HISTORY_BOL.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM)
    AND
      (HISTORY_BOL.FSCL_YR_NUM = PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_YR_NUM)
)
ON      (rowid = r)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     CASES_RCVD = TOTAL_BOL_SHIP_CASE_QTY;
```

Comment: With that, it kicks back saying that it is missing SET keyword

Comment: Just a question: are you running it in Oracle? Try again to copy and paste into Oracle SQL*plus or other tool of your choice. There is the `SET` keyword as far as I can see

Comment: Yes, I am running it through SQL Developer

Comment: why cant STANDARD QUERY LANGUAGE actually be standard and none of this convert crap...

Comment: column ambiguously defined...

hmm...  it may help if I informed that the (TOTAL_BOL_SHIP...etc)column was in the HISTORY_BOL table

Comment: Error at Command Line : 4 Column : 35
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

thank you for your on-going help.

Comment: I think I got it...  I named the AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY table at each "rowid" (which I hope was the correct table for each...